# UICollectionViewCells in a UICollectionView embedded in UITableView do not appear as desired

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having trouble displaying custom UICollectionViewCells in a UICollectionViewController's collection view.

Potentially important factors:

- I am creating my layouts programmatically, rather than using storyboard
- The collection view is a embedded as a subview of a UITableViewCell in a UITableView in my main UIViewController.
- I am using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout with a horizontal direction
- A cell fills up the entire width and height of its parent.

Things I've noticed in testing:

- In the current state of the app, cellForItemAt indexPath is only called a single time for the first cell that should be displayed.
- When the first cell is tapped, it disappears. I have not found a way to make it reappear.
- I can slide to where the other cells should be, and the correct number of "empty slots" are there, but the cells themselves do not appear.

I have tried to only include what I feel is necessary code to reduce the size of this post, but please let me know if there is anything I have failed to consider. Thank you for any help or suggestions. Additionally, I was hoping for some guidance when it comes to debugging using xcode in these kind of situations in the future. Does anyone know of any guides or books that give tips for hunting down issues like this? I have a bit of experience with gdb/visual studio's debugging tools, but Xcode and the framework are proving a bit tough for me when comes to debugging. Thanks again.

**Definition and constraints of table view:**

```
...

let trainingTableViewController = TrainingTableViewController()

lazy var trainingTableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    tableView.dataSource = trainingTableViewController
    tableView.delegate = trainingTableViewController
    tableView.register(TrainingLogoCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "trainingLogoID")
    tableView.register(TrainingProgressCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "trainingProgressID")
    tableView.register(TrainingProgressPageControlCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "trainingProgressPageControlID")
    tableView.register(TrainingWeekCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "trainingWeekID")
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tableView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    view.addSubview(trainingTableView)
    trainingTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true // TODO: see about anchoring to bottom of navigation
    trainingTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    trainingTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
    trainingTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

**TableView class with CollectionView cell**

```
class TrainingTableViewController: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "trainingLogoID", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "trainingProgressID", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "trainingProgressPageControlID", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "trainingWeekID", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }
    }

    ...        

class TrainingProgressCell: UITableViewCell {
    let trainingProgressCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        let collectionViewController = TrainingProgressCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionViewController.collectionView!.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionViewController.collectionView!.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionViewController.collectionView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return collectionViewController.collectionView!
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        backgroundColor = UIColor.init(rgb: 0x333333)
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

        contentView.addSubview(trainingProgressCollectionView)
        trainingProgressCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        trainingProgressCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        trainingProgressCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        trainingProgressCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

...
```

**My UICollectionView class**

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "trainingProgressCollectionViewID"

class TrainingProgressCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.register(TrainingProgressCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print(String(indexPath.row))
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TrainingProgressCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        cell.dayLabel.text = "Day " + String(indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }
}

class TrainingProgressCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var constraintsSetupDone = false

    let dayLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-ExtraBold", size: 18)
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(dayLabel)
        dayLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        dayLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your collectionView controller dies when the collectionView is returned. Therefore the delegate and datasource will become nil since it is weak and no references to the controller exist. This is not good code or good coding habits :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to ensure that the collection view controller was in scope. Its scope was originally restricted to the block of code in which the collection view was defined, therefore, the collection view no longer had a datasource or delegate.